# Multiple before_action's in Rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I have two methods that I wish to run in several controller actions.

```
  def get_offer
    @offer = Offer.find_by :uuid => params[:offer_id]
    if @offer.blank?
      error_response = ErrorResponse.new("Offer not found")
      render json: error_response, :status => :not_found and return
    end
  end

  def validate_api_v2
    api_version = params[:api_version]
    if api_version != api_version_to_validate
      error_response = ErrorResponse.new("API version not supported")
      render json: error_response, :status => :bad_request and return
    end
  end
```

How can I run both of them in actions `action_a`, `action_b` , only one in `action_c` and `action_d`, and none of them in `action_e`?

Answer (score 4):

You could probably do it like this:

```
before_action :get_offer, only: [:action_a, :action_b, :action_c]
before_action :validate_api_v2, only: [:action_a, :action_b, :action_d]
```

Edit: colons were missing for the second line only and action_id

Comment: Will these functions be executed in the same order as defined?

Comment: It is not guaranteed. If you need one of those to be the first for sure you can probably use `prepend_before_action`. You can read some here: http://hollandaiseparty.com/order-of-abstractcontrollercallbacks/

Answer (score 3):

Try this one

```
 before_filter :action_a, :action_b, only: [:action_c, :action_d]
```

Answer (score 1):

Move `get_offer` and `validate_api_v2` to `ApplicationController` and then in rest of your controllers, for example you can do:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :get_offer, :validate_api_v2, :only => [:action_a, :action_b]
end
```

and:

```
class SomeOtherController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :get_offer, :only => [:action_c, :action_d, :action_e]
  before_filter ::validate_api_v2, :only => [:action_c, :action_d]
end
```

I hope you get the point.

Answer (score 1):

write the methods in a controller concern. For example:

```
# app/controllers/concerns/example_concern.rb
module ExampleConcern
 extend ActiveSupport::Concern

 protected
 def get_offer
   @offer = Offer.find_by :uuid => params[:offer_id]
   if @offer.blank?
     error_response = ErrorResponse.new("Offer not found")
     render json: error_response, :status => :not_found and return
   end
 end

 def validate_api_v2
   api_version = params[:api_version]
   if api_version != api_version_to_validate
     error_response = ErrorResponse.new("API version not supported")
     render json: error_response, :status => :bad_request and return
   end
 end
end
```

Now in the controller, include the module in the concern and call the methods using before_action as required. For example:

```
# app/controllers/examples_controller.rb
class ExamplesController < ApplicationController
  include ExampleConcern

  before_action :get_offer, only: [:action_a, :action_b, :action_c]
  before_action :validate_api_v2, only: [:action_a, :action_b, :action_d]

  def action_a
  end
  def action_b
  end
  def action_c
  end
  def action_d
  end
  def action_e
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`except` comes in handy for some cases:

```
before_action :get_offer, only: [:action_a, :action_b, :action_c]
before_action :validate_api_v2, except: [:action_e, :action_c]
```